# Wordpress functions - get values without echo

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I programmatically use the data of the bult-in Wordpress functions.

E.g. I'd like to use the data of

```
the_author_meta('login_name');
```

in a php function. Problem: The function **echoes** the value by default. In order to use the actual value in a function I can think of using an output buffer like ...

```
ob_start();
the_author_meta('login_name');  
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

but I was hoping for a better (less bloated) solution.

Any idea how to get the echo values as simple return values instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `get_the_author_meta()` for return the value.

**Note:**  All of wordpress meta methods (the_post,the_author,the_page etc.) are supports the `get_` prefix